# How to list all tables and corresponding columns from a databricks database?

Tags: databricks

I am trying to get a list of tables and columns in a database, so I could find which tables have a particular column, the best I could find is use separate queries like one to show all tables , and then one to show all columns in one table, e.g. SHOW TABLES FROM database_name, SHOW COLUMNS FROM databasename.tablename. It will not be ideal when you have many tables to go through. Any solution out there at all?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to fetch all metadata in one call.  You can only do `show databases`, `show tables in ...`, `describe table ...`.  There is also `spark.catalog.listTables`, etc., but they could be slower than corresponding SQL queries.

I answered to [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783824/generate-database-schema-diagram-for-databricks/63799085#63799085) yesterday - you can find code there.